# How to translate this sql query to Core Data predicate

Tags: ios

Please help me to convert this sql statement into predicate

```
SELECT path 
FROM store
WHERE index=cnt
```

Comment: Thanks for giving negative marking to this question. I would appreciate if someone can help to newbies who is trying to learn Xcode.

Comment: That is exactly what we are here for, to help.  However, we would like to _help_ you with your work as opposed to doing it for you.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am able to save the information in the Core data but I am not sure how to fetch the data using predicate. I want to retrieve the data using above mentioned SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"store" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"index == %d", cnt]
```

Then you can access 'path' from your own NSManagedObject subclass.
Please tell us what you have tried in order for us to provide you a proper answer.
I think you need to look for some examples or tutorials on Coredata.